# PyQt4 not returning full webpage content

Tags: python, qt, web-scraping, pyqt4

I'm trying to scrape user reviews off of allrecipes.com.  Because allrecipes uses javascript, Requests won't work but PyQt4 should.  The data I want is contained in article with class = 'profile-review-card'.

When I look through the content that is returned, while it contains more then Requests gave me, it is still missing the portions I want.  Why am I still not getting the full page content?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Render(QWebPage):
  def __init__(self, url):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QWebPage.__init__(self)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
    self.app.exec_()

  def _loadFinished(self, result):
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()
    self.app.quit()

url = 'http://allrecipes.com/cook/2010/reviews/'
# use pyqt4 to render it
r = Render(url)
# pull the page content
result = r.frame.toHtml()
#use beautifulsoup to search through the content
x = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')
#search for recipes reviewed, a is empty list, it's not finding the data I want
a = x.find_all('article', class_="profile-review-card")
```

UPDATE: I've figured out why it's not returning the content it should.  When you load an allrecipes user reviews page once the browser loads the page, there is a loading icon before the reviews appear.  I've found that PyQt4 gets stuck on this loading procedure.

[image: loading] [image: loaded]

When I boot up a PyQt4 browser window and load the webpage using

```
url = 'http://allrecipes.com/cook/22/reviews/'
import sys
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
browser = QWebView()
browser.load(QUrl(url))
browser.show()
app.exec_()
```

it get's stuck on this

[image: pyqt window browser]

so apparently PyQt4 is not able to load up the page correctly! How can I fix this?

Not sure if this is related but I've noticed that when I load an allrecipe recipe page, it works but returns Internet Plug-In load errors.  Is it possible some missing plug-ins are the issue?

```
2016-05-06 19:06:39.520 Python[17348:178927] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/DirectorShockwave.plugin/Contents/MacOS/DirectorShockwave:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/DirectorShockwave.plugin/Contents/MacOS/DirectorShockwave, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/DirectorShockwave.plugin/Contents/MacOS/DirectorShockwave: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2016-05-06 19:06:39.547 Python[17348:178927] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin/Contents/MacOS/agcore:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin/Contents/MacOS/agcore, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin/Contents/MacOS/agcore: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2016-05-06 19:06:39.548 Python[17348:178927] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/OVSHelper.plugin/Contents/MacOS/OVSHelper:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/OVSHelper.plugin/Contents/MacOS/OVSHelper, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/OVSHelper.plugin/Contents/MacOS/OVSHelper: mach-o, but wrong architecture
Vector smash protection is enabled.
objc[17348]: Class MacCocoaSocketServerHelperRtc is implemented in both /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/googletalkbrowserplugin and /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/o1dbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/o1dbrowserplugin. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2016-05-06 19:06:39.646 Python[17348:178927] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/DivX Web Player.plugin/Contents/MacOS/DivX Web Player:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/DivX Web Player.plugin/Contents/MacOS/DivX Web Player, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/DivX Web Player.plugin/Contents/MacOS/DivX Web Player: mach-o, but wrong architecture
objc[17348]: Class AdobePDFProgressView is implemented in both /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/AdobePDFViewer.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AdobePDFViewer and /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/AdobePDFViewerNPAPI.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AdobePDFViewerNPAPI. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[17348]: Class ObjCTimerObject is implemented in both /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/AdobePDFViewer.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AdobePDFViewer and /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/AdobePDFViewerNPAPI.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AdobePDFViewerNPAPI. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2016-05-06 19:06:39.653 Python[17348:178927] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7f8bf47249f0 </Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Unused> (not loaded)
2016-05-06 19:06:39.654 Python[17348:178927] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7f8bf1dd8650 </Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Disabled Plug-Ins> (not loaded)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
```

Comment: What do you get versus what do you want?

Comment: Ideally, I'd want all the content shown by inspect in Chrome.  Looking through what I get, while I get the 'parent' of the article I want, it doesn't include all the 'children' that I want.

I'm sure im butchering the terminology but symbolically its like this:
-inspect shows A:{B,C,D,E}
-the content that is returned to me is only A:{B,C}, some elements are missing.  

Sorry if this doesn't make sense.